# Doing something you enjoy so often you get tired of it

Tags: single-word-requests

I have this bad habit, where I listen to a song I recently found and really liked, then replay it a million times to the point where hearing it again doesn't really do anything for me anymore.

Is there a specific word for this? Doesn't need to be listening to music, could be any activity that brings you joy, but doesn't after you've done it a million times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's **[ad nauseam](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad_nauseam)**:

> Having been done or repeated so often that it has become annoying or tiresome.

Another common phrase is *doing something **[to death](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_death)***. In your example of music, you could say that you "played the song to death".